# Recognize Back/Forward browser buttons in Angular2

Tags: javascript, browser, angular2-routing

I am programming an Angular2 application and I want to handle the back and forward button from the browser.

The idea is to write in the console a message on "back" click and different message on "forward" click.

I used this code:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private location: Location) {}
    ngOnInit() {
       this.location.subscribe(x => { [custom message]  });
    }
}
```

The Problem is: I cannot recognize the click if it is back or forward to write the correct message in the console.

How can I check it in angular2? I don't know what should I exactly search on google. All the answers were about to handle the event but to differentiate it.

P.S. it works for me if it is in javascript. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to differentiate between back and forward buttons in Angular (5) also, in my case for animating route transitions. I couldn't find a solution, so here's one I came up with.

Add the following to a service.

```
private popState: boolean = false;
private urlHistory: string[] = [];
private popSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

constructor(private location: Location, private router: Router) {

    location.subscribe(event => {
        let fwd = false;
        if (this.urlHistory.lastIndexOf(event.url)) {
            this.urlHistory.push(event.url);
        }
        else {
            fwd = true;
            this.urlHistory.pop();
        }
        this.popState = true;
        this.popSubject.next(fwd);
    })

    router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            if (!this.popState)
                this.urlHistory = [this.router.url];
            this.popState = false;
        }
    })
}

get popEvent$() {
    return this.popSubject.asObservable();
}
```

Imports:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

Remove popSubject and popEvent$ if you don't need to listen for the event externally.

Comment: I came up with almost the same idea, but I did it by versioning the URL. So, there will be a guide version added to the URL, which will be saved and an array to be located later to detect if it is backward or forward. I guess it is the same idea here. But you did it with Subject, I did it with redux.

Comment: Dont you think the logic has probably a typo where you check lasIindexOf? it will never go in else. I tried a psuedo code in JS and never went in else because lastindexOf will either return -1 or index which are both truthy for 
"if" condition. Do you want to check === -1 in first if?

Comment: When you pop the state forward to the first URL in the history, you reach index 0.